# ActiveMQ broker-url in Spring Dropwizard

Tags: spring-boot, activemq-classic, dropwizard, spring-jms

I am new to Spring Dropwizard and want to configure ActiveMQ on a simple client app.

I know that below configuration works in Spring Boot when placed in `application.properties` using Spring autoconfigure.

```
spring.activemq.brokerUrl=tcp://0.0.0.0:61616
spring.jms.cache.enabled=false
```

But how can we achieve the same thing in Spring Dropwizard? How can we place these properties in `config.yml` so that my client can start listening to JMS messages?

I tried the below config but Spring is not getting read from the config

```
spring:
   activemq:
       broker-url: tcp://localhost:61616
```

How can we configure same config in Dropwizard config with minimal changes to start listening to topic?

Comment: What is "Spring Dropwizard" exactly? Spring and Dropwizard are independent, unique projects. Configuration for one won't work for the other.

Comment: @JustinBertram Thanks for this info. Can you please guide me how to configure activemq and jms for dropwizard

Comment: @JustinBertram : If we have a springboot custom starter, then can we use it with this dropwizard app by using the jar in pom?

Comment: Unfortunately I have no idea. I've never used Dropwizard. Perhaps you should close this question and ask a new one specifically about that.